# How to add custom attributes for Azure AD B2B user

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

How can be added custom attribute for user in Azure AD B2B using API?

A found a way for [External Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/user-flow-add-custom-attributes) but I'm looking for custom attributes regardless of user type.
For example, I want to have the attribute "FavoriteColor" for every user (member or guest)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft Graph API [Create extensionProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Specify the `targetObjects` as "User".

An example (you can use any of your app registrations for {object id of the app registration}):

```
Post https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{object id of the app registration}/extensionProperties

{"name":"customAttribute","dataType":"string","targetObjects":["User"]}
```

It will generate an extension property named `extension_{client id of the app registration without "-"}_customAttribute`.

Then you can update the extension property for the member or guest user:

```
Patch https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}

{"extension_{client id of the Azure AD application without "-"}_customAttribute":"value"}
```

Use [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to have a quick test.

[Microsoft Graph auth overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/) and [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview) for your reference.